# google map can get latitude and longitude, but can't display the map via android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

It's a bit weird that I did everything to setup the google map, and can get map successfully. But why the map could not shown, only display an white board and zoom buttons.

Here is what I did:

1. Make google map service on.
2. Enable the permission, use debug api key and set openGL on in
   manifest.
3. I use SupportMapFragment both in layout and java as I need to
   compatible above 2.2 version.

anyone can help?

Comment: This can be the answer to your question " http://stackoverflow.com/a/15658739/1081355 "

Comment: are you viewing in EMulator or device??

Comment: I am viewing the map in device. and the package name are same.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger I am viewing the map in device. I make sure the permission is good. the package name also good. I've checked lots of articles of the blank screen, however they can't resolve my problem.

Comment: I think you should try again by getting debu.keystore and get certificate key and then get new API key fro MAP v2 and do this things again.

Comment: I had the same problem when i first implemented Map. that time i have regenerated the key and problem was resolved.