# google maps V2 not working any more

Tags: android

My phone does not loads the map which is created using Google Maps V2.
Previously it was working fine, now i just get a blank screen with Google keyword in the Bottom left screen and zoom in controls in the right.

below is the screenshot-

[image]

Comment: Tiles are getting loaded make sure u r connected to good internet connection

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658526/google-maps-android-v2-blank-screen

Answer (score 0):

May be you are wrong with Map API_KEY. Make sure you have correct one in Manifest file.